# Is there a way to programmatically create a facebook product catalog?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to create Facebook product catalogs programmatically and i don't see any methods in the graph API, Marketing API, or Catalog Batch API. Does anyone know if this is possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After what seemed like an endless amount of time I finally found the documentation for it.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/product-catalog#Creating

Comment: that page does not help if you try with cURL: " Deprecated endpoint as of V2.11 is deprecated for versions v2.11 and higher"